# Transform Queryset Into string

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a `Django` / `Python QuerySet` that Looks like this:

`[{'first_name': 'hans', 'last_name': 'baust'}]`

And I would like to only have something like

```
variable name1 that contains 'hans'

variable name2 that contains 'hans'
```

I cannot make it with the current Google results...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by iterating through the queryset.

```py
# queryset = [{'first_name': 'hans', 'last_name': 'baust'}]
result = ''

for obj in queryset:
    for key, value in obj.items():
        result += '{} {} '.format(key, value)
result = result.strip()
# result = 'first_name hans last_name baust'
```

If this is not the type of output you want kindly update your question to contain a output sample.